# I am getting more stars than specified in the view

Tags: android, ratingbar

I want to use `RatingBar` in the layout i am using. it should contain maximum 5 stars. the problem now is, when i use the below posted code, I get a `RatingBar` with 
more than 5 stars

i would like to know how should i modify the below costed view so I can use exactly 5 start

**code**:

```
<RatingBar
      android:id="@+id/cardViewRatingBar"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="3"
      android:numStars="5"
      android:rating="4"
      android:stepSize=".5"
      style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"/>
```

Comment: I think you should change `android:layout_width=0dp`  to `wrap_content`

Comment: @Anatolii thanks..but no i dont have access to gravity property, i want to place the ratingbar to be at the end

Comment: Why have you accepted the answer then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is likely down to the layout width. I don't think ratingBar can be successfully set to anything other than "wrap_content" otherwise you end up with the problem that you have described.

Try this:

```
<RatingBar
      android:id="@+id/cardViewRatingBar"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:numStars="5"
      android:rating="4"
      android:stepSize=".5"
      style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"/>
```

As a result you may have to do a little work with the parent layout to set it how you want in the activity, or you can try different style settings for the bar.